# combine results of multiple python scripts in one statement

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have about 4 different python scripts that all return a list of dictionaries.  I would like to combine the results from all of the scripts and then print it out to the console, but if possible I would like to combine them in one line of code.  Here is an incorrect attempt at what I am trying to do.. (each call to main returns a generator object)

```
from Parsers import ctd, test1, test2


def main():
    results = ctd.main() + ctd.test1() + ctd.test2()

    for i in results:
        print i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to join the results of several iterables (in your case, generators) together:

```
for i in itertools.chain(ctd.main(), ctd.test1(), ctd.test2()):
    print i
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I am looking for.  I have a way to get it to work without it, but it seems kind of clunky.  This is much better!